# Find a nested object inside an arrary of objects based on the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find

I've an array of objects in which I need to find the object which has the same value as that of the string.
I've tried this and it works.

But, is there a way to optimize it without using map?

Code:

```js
const arr = [{
    label: 'A',
    options: [{
        label: 'abc',
        value: 'abc'
      },
      {
        label: 'bcd',
        value: 'bcd'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'B',
    options: [{
        label: 'cde',
        value: 'cde'
      },
      {
        label: 'def',
        value: 'def'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'C',
    options: [{
        label: 'efg',
        value: 'efg'
      },
      {
        label: 'fgh',
        value: 'fgh'
      }
    ]
  }
];
const str = 'cde';
const result = arr.map(obj => obj.options.find(item => item.value === str)).find(val => val !== undefined);
console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: That is a question more suited for codereview

Comment: You could use simple `for-loop`s in order to get rid of `.map()`

Comment: If the value you look for is unique or you only need the first found, use a loop and `break` when found to avoid unnecessary loop turns

Comment: This is a poor and too broad question. You should specify an array size and some other circumstances. Why do you dislike the handy `map` method? In what way do you mean 'optimization'? E.g. large arrays could be sorted once and afterwards searched multiple times with a binary search algorithm. In this case you should not rely on the original elements order/indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you don't need or want `map` followed by `find`. Just a loop:

```
let result;
for (const obj of arr) {
    result = obj.options.find(({value}) => value === str);
    if (result) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const arr = [{
    label: 'A',
    options: [{
        label: 'abc',
        value: 'abc'
      },
      {
        label: 'bcd',
        value: 'bcd'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'B',
    options: [{
        label: 'cde',
        value: 'cde'
      },
      {
        label: 'def',
        value: 'def'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    label: 'C',
    options: [{
        label: 'efg',
        value: 'efg'
      },
      {
        label: 'fgh',
        value: 'fgh'
      }
    ]
  }
];
const str = 'cde';
let result;
for (const obj of arr) {
    result = obj.options.find(({value}) => value === str);
    if (result) {
        break;
    }
}
console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: When we speak about optimization, a simple indexed `for` loop with a pre-cached `arr.length` would perform even faster on large arrays than `for of`.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone - Quite possibly, quite possibly not; it depends on how well the JavaScript engine optimizes `for-of` loops when you're dealing with an actual array (rather than just an iterable) vs how well it optimizes `for` loops. But in this code, I'd expect the `find` to dominate anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) with an empty array as default value.

The result is an array with matching result.

```js
const
    arr = [{ label: 'A', options: [{ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' }, { label: 'bcd', value: 'bcd' }] }, { label: 'B', options: [{ label: 'cde', value: 'cde' }, { label: 'def', value: 'def' } ] }, { label: 'C', options: [{ label: 'efg', value: 'efg' }, { label: 'fgh', value: 'fgh' }] }];
    str = 'cde';
    result = arr.flatMap(obj => obj.options.find(item => item.value === str) || []);

console.log('result', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `find` inside the `map` which is `O(nk)`;

You can fetch all the `options` then `flat` the array to `find` the required object.

```js
const arr = [{
 label: 'A',
 options: [{
   label: 'abc',
   value: 'abc'
  },
  {
   label: 'bcd',
   value: 'bcd'
  }
 ]
},
{
 label: 'B',
 options: [{
   label: 'cde',
   value: 'cde'
  },
  {
   label: 'def',
   value: 'def'
  }
 ]
},
{
 label: 'C',
 options: [{
   label: 'efg',
   value: 'efg'
  },
  {
   label: 'fgh',
   value: 'fgh'
  }
 ]
}
];

const str = 'cde';
const result = arr.map(({options}) => options).flat().find(({value}) => value === str)
console.log('result', result);
```

Comment: the `.find()` is used on the `options` array (not the `arr` array), so the t.c would be O(nk) rather than n^2, where `n` is the number of elements in the `arr` and `k` is the max number of elements in an `options` arrays.

Comment: ahh, correct missed that. thanks. But still moving it out reduces the complexity, so better do.

Answer (score 0):

Depending of your needs, you can do this:

```js
const arr = [{ label: 'A', options: [{ label: 'abc', value: 'abc' }, { label: 'bcd', value: 'bcd' }] }, { label: 'B', options: [{ label: 'cde', value: 'cde' }, { label: 'def', value: 'def' } ] }, { label: 'C', options: [{ label: 'efg', value: 'efg' }, { label: 'fgh', value: 'fgh' }] }];

const re1 = /"value":"cde"/
const testStr = JSON.stringify(arr);
console.log(""+testStr)

console.log(re1.test(testStr)) // exists

const re2 = /"label":"(\w)+","value":"cde"/g

console.log(testStr.match(re2)) // label
```

Comment: `I need to find the object`, also it will be much slower than the OP's solution.

Answer (score 0):

find in the underscore library will avoid using map in this scenario:

```
var myObj = _.find(arr, (obj) => {
    return _.find(obj.options, (elt) => elt.value === str);
});
```